# Re-upload enhanced SAPUI5 Code to ABAP repository

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-basis

I managed to download the code of a SAPUI5 Application (standard app) in ABAP Repository using SE38's program:`/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD` to enhance (add QRCode Scanner feature to the app and make it runnable on mobile device).

Now I wonder how I re-upload this code back to ABAP Repository. My issues are:

- I cannot replace the old app('Z-' prefix is required to upload). Is there anyhow I can replace the old code (upload new code under the old app's name)?
- Even if I upload as a new app, it requires `manifest.json` file, but the old code hierarchy doesn't contain it. (it used lib `sap.ca.scfld.md.ComponentBase.js` and `sap.ca.scfld.md.ConfigurationBase.js` to configure)

Any suggestions for my issues?

Comment: Are you using the WebIDE? You'll want to create an extension project, *not* change the existing application.

Comment: I will try. thank you sir